# FramerJS: how can you animate similar layers in different locations on screen, simultaneously and repeatingly?

Tags: animation, coffeescript, framerjs

I am trying to create a scene of blinking stars where essentially you have multiple, similar layers (difference in size and x/y coordinates) animating across different locations on the screen, simultaneously and infinitely.

I have attempted to create this by looping through X amount of layers I created and animating them between states. It appears the first state animates for all of the layers, however, only the first layer created in the array is animating on the second state, and is the only one looping its animations.

Here is a link to my project with code: https://framer.cloud/JlZul

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant code here in the question. Thanks!